# Turbulence strength from turbulence intensity?

Tags: turbulence

I do not have a lot of knowledge in aerodynamics but I need to be able to derive turbulence strength (Cv2 and Ct2 - so called turbulence structural parameters I think) from turbulence intensity. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How is the turbulent intensity defined in your case? Is it the flow field?

Comment: It is defined as folows: TI = 100*σ/μ [%], where μ = mean(u) and σ=stdev(u)  with u being the horizontal wind speed.

Comment: This is reasonable to ask here, but you might get better answers from engineering.stackexchange

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon thanks a lot, I will try that as well :)